# How can i create a criteria for This SQL

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I Stuck in this query. If any body know the Criteria of NHibernate please help me

```
 select * from ViewFabricStock VFS where VFS.REORDER_METER > VFS.VIRTUAL_STOCK
```

`VFS.REORDER_METER` ,`VFS.VIRTUAL_STOCK` is a model property

i would like also know about this query select * from ViewFabricStock VFS where fabricName like LocalizeFabricName

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are finding issues comparing two Properties of the same entity

Trying using the interface `Criteria.XProperty` where X = `Ge` or `Le` or `Eq`

Using Criteria :

```
session.CreateCriteria<ViewFabricStock>("VFS")
        .Add(Restrictions.GeProperty("REORDER_METER","VIRTUAL_STOCK")
```

Using QueryOver :

```
ViewFabricStock vfs = null
session.QueryOver<ViewFabricStock>(() => vfs)
        .Where(Restrictions.GeProperty(
                        Projections.Property(() => realm.REORDER_METER), 
                        Projections.Property(() => realm.VIRTUAL_STOCK)));
```